# Ms Powershell 5: Displaying highlighted item from a Listbox

Tags: powershell, listbox

I want to be able to display the currently highlighted item from a scrolling list box, without having to click it.
I have set up the list box so that only one item is displayed. The selection changes via the scroll buttons. I want to be able to read the item displayed without having to click it - so .Add_Click is not suitable.
Example code below:

Many thanks

```
# Listbox test

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
# set up form
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "List Box Test"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,200)
    $form.StartPosition = "Manual"
    $form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
# Set up list
    $List1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $List1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)        
    $List1.Height = 30
    $List1.Width = 150
    $List1.font = 'arial, 16pt'
    [void] $List1.Items.Add('Clubs')
    [void] $List1.Items.Add('Diamonds')
    [void] $List1.Items.Add('Hearts')
    [void] $List1.Items.Add('Spades')
    $form.Controls.Add($List1)

# Question: how do I get the highlighted item from the list box to show here, before it is clicked?
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# display selection
    $TextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $TextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
    $TextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)
    $TextBox1.Font = 'arial, 12pt'
    $TextBox1.text = "Highlighted item to show here ..."
    $form.Controls.Add($TextBox1)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# set up button
    $Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100)
    $Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
    $Button1.Text = "OK"
    $Button1.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

    $form.Controls.Add($Button1)
    
    $form.Topmost = $true

    $null = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to the listbox:

```
$List1.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $TextBox1.Text = $this.SelectedItem.ToString()  # or do: $this.items[$this.SelectedIndex].ToString()
})
```

<sup>Since a Listbox only contains text, you could leave out the `.ToString()`.</sup>

P.S. Don't forget to remove the form from memory when all done with

```
$form.Dispose()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The only work-around that I've found is to remove the control and replace it. I think it's because the list box is not actually selecting anything - it's just scrolling through the list of items.
The other way would be to change the design of the form and include buttons for stepping through the list of items, showing the selected one in a text box.

Comment: @NedLudd Then why does it work for me? I have added a gif to demonstrate. Isn't this what you wanted?